# MAMP is giving a blank screen, Not loading mysql

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

Firstly, I have seen other questions like this but not quite the same. I am new to php and am only using it to install Wordpress.org.

The issue is that my website is coming up blank with with it failing to load php_mysql.dll even though the MySQL Server indicator is green. Here is the errorlog from phperror:

```
[08-Aug-2017 00:57:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.5\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
[08-Aug-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.5\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I read that it may have to do with formatting and I know enough about php to go through files and check for errors but besides php_mysql I have no clue as to where to start looking. Not sure if I have given enough information, but I hope it's enough.

Update:
Here is coding from my configuration file -

Extentions:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll 
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

[MySQL]:

```
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
```

Comment: The mysql_* functions are no longer supported with PHP 7, so you can likely comment that out in the ini file. However, there should be a php_mysqli and/or php_pdo_mysql dll's instead.

Comment: This question remains unresolved, I've been trying to fix this for about two weeks :/

Comment: Then you might have an old Wordpress version, perhaps? In your PHP list of dll's, there is: `extension=php_mysqli.dll` (with the 'i' is listed), but there is **NO** listing for: `php_mysql.dll` (and there should not be)  PHP 7 should not even be looking for the old DLL. Check the [mysql] area of the php.ini file and make sure there is nothing there. Also search the file to ensure that `php_mysql.dll` is NOT found anywhere. If it is, comment-out the line, and make sure to restart Apache after the change is saved. In case it might matter, what MAMP version do you have?

Comment: I deleted the mysql extension. My MAMP version is 3.3.1. I am going to re-install everything just to have a clear start. I don't understand they wouldn't just edit the mysql stuff out themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The php_mysql extension was depreciated and removed completely from PHP 7. You should remove the extension from your configuration so it doesn't attempt to load.

Instead of using `mysql`, you'll want to use `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: Added some more info :)

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: Okay so I've done that but I received an error about the configuration not being valid. It's now blank with no errors appearing in phperror. I tried deleting all [MySQL] in the configuration and it didn't help so I put it back.

Comment: You could post your configuration file.

Comment: It's too large to post. I am new to this site so I'm not sure about how to post it. Are there any parts in particular you are looking for? Sorry for the inconvenience, and I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Just post any lines that have mysql in it. There shouldn't be too many.